# Restauração de Backup Mysql não insere todas as Tabelas

Tags: mysql

Tenho um banco de dados `MySql`, onde realizei um **backup** de todos os dados de determinado banco (foi salvo realmente todos os dados dentro de um arquivo `.sql`) porém quando fui **resetar** usando este arquivo não foi inserido todos as tabelas dos banco (Total 18, Inseridas 14)

**Perguntas:**

1. Qual o Real motivo deste problema ?
2. Como resolver ?

**Obs1:** Notei que foi salvo as tabelas em ordem alfabética logo pude notar um desencontro de Chaves Primarias e Estrangeiras (Inserção de estrangeiras antes das chaves estrangeiras) (Possível problema)

**Obs2:** MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.6.21, for Win32 (x86), InnoDB

Comment: Isso já aconteceu comigo,porem, eu estava usando o postgresSQL , eu havia  feito algumas mudanças na configuração do backup e esqueci de voltar ao estado normal do banco.Só resolvi removendo  o banco e reinstalando! Mas minha sorte é que tinha outros backups!! Você  só fez um único backup?

Comment: @PenaPintada sim este é o único Backup (tem todas as tabelas só na hora de inserir não insere todos)

Comment: Salvo engano, o MySQL dump , sem parâmetros extras não trava os acessos as tabelas, podendo gerar falta de integridade entre elas se tiver aplicação acessando o banco. Se este arquivo SQL é a unica coisa que tem agora, sugiro edita-lo, comentar/remover todas as constraints manualmente e tentar carrega-lo... se carregar, então o problema realmente é a falta de integridade. Também sugiro dar uma olhada no conteúdo do arquivo para ver se as tabelas "faltantes" realmente estão lá.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o arquivo em questão não esta danificado e o erro é apenas (Chaves Primarias e Estrangeiras), basta executar este procedimento no arquivo do backup:

1 Após o comando `use bancodedados;` coloque o comando

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

para desativar as chaves, tendo feita a injeção no final coloque o comando a seguir no final do script para reativar as chaves

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```